# What scenario is covered when not awaiting an async method and immediately evaluating IsCompleted?

Tags: c#, async-await

The [`BackgroundService`](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/898f0947fa4271d08e88daea503be6fd8ffb3c4f/src/Hosting/Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs) class contains the following code:

```
public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Store the task we're executing
    _executingTask = ExecuteAsync(_stoppingCts.Token);

    // If the task is completed then return it, this will bubble cancellation and failure to the caller
    if (_executingTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        return _executingTask;
    }

    // Otherwise it's running
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

I've read https://www.markopapic.com/csharp-under-the-hood-async-await/ which leads me to assume that all code of `ExecuteAsync` up to its first (if any) `await ...`, is executed before `if (_executingTask.IsCompleted)` is reached. So if any exception occurs in that part of `ExecuteAsync`, or if `ExecuteAsync` returns `Task.CompletedTask`, that will lead to executing `return _executingTask;`.

Is my understanding of this correct?

Comment: Note: I wouldn't be surprised if this is a duplicate of a more general async/await question, but the large amount of async/await questions on SO don't make it easy to find the information I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So if any exception occurs in that part of ExecuteAsync, or if ExecuteAsync returns Task.CompletedTask, that will lead to executing return _executingTask;

More generally, if `ExecuteAsync` completes synchronously, then `StartAsync` returns the task returned from `ExecuteAsync`.

In this particular case (with background services), I believe it's intended to handle things like precondition checks, which are generally done synchronously at the beginning of an asynchronous method. So if a background service synchronously determines it can't run, then `StartAsync` will return a faulted task.

This kind of code is extremely rare, and the design is questionable. E.g., if a background service *asynchronously* determines that it can't run, then there's no notification of that. I think the behavior would be more consistent to remove the whole `if (_executingTask.IsCompleted)` block, or else change the `ExecuteAsync` abstraction into separate `InitializeAsync` and `ExecuteAsync` parts.